# How to show only 1 calendar in vue2-daterange-picker?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I just want to ask if there is a way to show only 1 calendar in the daterange picker.

I am using this component.

https://innologica.github.io/vue2-daterange-picker/

[image]

Any answers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution to hide the second calendar by overriding the CSS. I'm posting my answer here to help other people who might encounter this problem.

```
.daterangepicker {min-width: unset !important;}

.drp-calendar.col.right{ display: none; }
```